# PyTorch: wrapping multiple records in one file?

Tags: image, pytorch, record, tfrecord

Is there a standard way of encoding multiple records (in this case, data from multiple .png or .jpeg images) in one file that PyTorch can read? Something similar to TensorFlow's "TFRecord" or MXNet's "RecordIO", but for PyTorch.

I need to download image data from S3 for inference, and it's much slower if my image data is in many small .jpg files rather than fewer files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is to store batches of images together in a single `npz` file. Numpy's [`np.savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) lets you save multiple arrays compressed into a single file. Then load the file as np arrays and use `torch.from_numpy` to convert to tensors.

Comment: This was my thought as well. I was a bit worried about padding images and the shape of the model (whether it accepts multiple images at once, and if so, whether the images need to be padded to be the same size), but it seems the best-supported PyTorch solution.